# What am I doing wrong here in the PlotLegends specification?

Tags: legending

Here is my code:

```
Plot[{(81*Sqrt[3])/(4 \[Pi]) (r + r^2)^2/(1 + r + r^2)^4, 
  27/8 (r + r^2)/(1 + r + r^2)^(5/2), 1/(1 + r)^2}, {r, 0, 6}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, {Red, 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {Gray, Dashing[{0.02, 0.015}], 
    Thickness[0.005]}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{White, {Red, Thickness[0.007]}, {Blue, 
      Thickness[0.007]}, {Gray, Dashing[{0.02, 0.015}], 
      Thickness[0.007]}}, {"", "\[Beta]=1", "\[Beta]=2", "Poisson"}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 25}], Scaled[{0.5, 0.7}]], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

This gives me:
[image]

Here I have to write "White" and " " in the LineLegend so that it gives me correct output, but it makes no sense to have that in the code since I have three elements to plot in the Plot function. If I remove "White" and " ", it does not give me the correct output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I cannot understand this phrase: `have to write "White"` when you know that you have only `have three elements to plot` ?

Comment: I was trying different things for the code to work, apparently, it worked when I added that part in the code, which was very surprising. I don't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inherit the colors for the legend if the functions and legend orders are consistent. To reproduce the plot that you show:

```
Plot[{
  27/8 (r + r^2)/(1 + r + r^2)^(5/2),
  (81*Sqrt[3])/(4 π) (r + r^2)^2/(1 + r + r^2)^4,
  1/(1 + r)^2},
 {r, 0, 6},
 PlotStyle -> {
   {Red, Thickness[0.005]},
   {Blue, Thickness[0.005]},
   {Gray, Dashing[{0.02, 0.015}], Thickness[0.005]}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   {"β=1", "β=2", "Poisson"},
   Scaled[{0.5, 0.7}]],
 AxesLabel -> {Style[r, 14], None},
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in the documentation for [`LineLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineLegend.html) under `Scope > Data`, use [`Directive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html) to combine directives in a style.

```
legend = LineLegend[{
    Directive[{Red, Thickness[0.007]}], 
    Directive[{Blue, Thickness[0.007]}], 
    Directive[{Gray, Dashing[{0.02, 0.015}], Thickness[0.007]}]
   }, {"β=1", "β=2", "Poisson"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 25}];

Plot[{(81*Sqrt[3])/(4 π) (r + r^2)^2/(1 + r + r^2)^4, 
  27/8 (r + r^2)/(1 + r + r^2)^(5/2), 1/(1 + r)^2}, {r, 0, 6}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, {Red, 
    Thickness[0.005]}, {Gray, Dashing[{0.02, 0.015}], 
    Thickness[0.005]}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[legend, Scaled[{0.5, 0.7}]], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Plot]

If you don't like writing `Directive` so many times, use [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html).

```
legend = LineLegend[
   Directive /@ {{Red, Thickness[0.007]}, {Blue, 
      Thickness[0.007]}, {Gray, Dashing[{0.02, 0.015}], 
      Thickness[0.007]}}, {"β=1", "β=2", "Poisson"}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 25}];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!